# PERC - Create RAID1 from single drive without losing data

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I have a PowerEdge 2950. I have one 1TB drive with critical data on it that has been running alone for months, and I want to add a second 1TB drive and make a RAID1 out of these 2 drives, but without losing the data on the first 1TB drive.

From PERC, is this something that can be done without having to make a complete backup of the data and restore it into the new RAID1 drive?

Answer (score 1):

what you trying to do is possible... but more in a real hackish way.

but in my opinion:

- make a downtime
- backup the data from RAID1
- rebuild the new RAID1
- restore the data from the Backup you made

http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/dell-perc6-extend.html